# Prestashop webvolty, can't change default template, goes back to original state

Tags: prestashop

I am trying to edit prestashop 1.7.5 module of webvolty template. It's just a minor tweak (I want to change translation but don't know how to use default translation files). I just edit `display_compare_product.tpl` file on my PC, delete one at remote location and upload edited. Every time I do that it almost instantly goes to original state (I can see file size goes to original state after 0,1 s). Any way to force this process or can anyone help me with translation of a string? All i see is `pl.php` file at `translations` folder but it's empty.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you can do that through:
International > Translations

I just did not know that you can also translate ANY string from ANY module with that feature.